# Does adding a bit of red wine to white wine change the resulting drinks' status vis-a-vis kiddush?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, grapes-wine, kiddush, color

There are various opinions regarding the acceptance of white wine for [kiddush](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kiddush). My question is, if say one has a full bottle of white, if they pour a cup that is majority white (80%+), but are able to add just enough red (wine) to influence it's appearance, so that it looks red (or reddish), would this mixture be considered red according to those that require red?

UPDATE: I found this link which actually brings up the activity in question as to whether or not it is permissible vis-a-vis the melacha of [dyeing](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=760). It's not directly stated as acceptable/effective nor discussed (so I'm keeping the question open), but it's implied that it was something people *wanted* to do.

Comment: I suppose it depends if red is because of Kavod or quality.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was checking the relevant sifim in the SA, and it seems like the opinions of the Ramban (against white) and the Rambam (against mevushal)  (both rejected) are both based on whats fitting for the mizbeach

Comment: Yes, yes. But the question still follows: is it not allowed on the Mizbeach because of Kavod or quality?

Comment: @DoubleAA Kavod being (related to) something intrinsic and quality being external?

Comment: I guess I mean to say is white wine not good wine, or just it doesn't look presentable even if it tastes totally normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rabbi Ovadia Yosef in Yalkut Yosef ([272, 6](http://www.yalkut.info/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%91-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%96%D7%94-%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D/)) says that only if one doesn't have enough red wine (which is preferred for *kiddush* over white wine), one should add the little amount of red wine he has to white wine, so that the color becomes red:

> אם לא מצא יין אדום הכשר לברכת בורא פרי הגפן, יקדש על יין לבן, ויערב בו מעט יין אדום כדי להאדימו.‏

He goes on to explain why this is not considered forbidden "dyeing" (his opinion is that this isn't relevant with drinks).

So the highest preference is for red wine, and only if there isn't enough, your solution is preferred over pure white wine.